# Finding the probabilities of the occurrence of each element in a vector

Tags: matlab

I have this type of data:

```
         1
         2
         3
         3
         4
         1
```

Now , I want to maintain two separate arrays:
one will keep the above numbers and the other will keep thier corresponding probabilities

```
values      values_counter (proabability)
   1                     2/6
   2                     1/6
   3                     2/6
   4                     1/6
```

I have written the following code but it prints out all the 6 numbers ie 1 2 3 3 4 1 and their proabilities as uniform.
Please help me where I am making the mistake in the code given below

```
 values=[];
 values_counter=[];
for d=1:1:648
size_of_array=size(values);
values_array_size=size_of_array(2);

if(values_array_size~=0)

for b=1:1:values_array_size
    if (columnB(d)~=values(b))
        values(values_array_size+1)=columnB(d); // columnB(d) has different values (may   have duplicate values)
        dfastates_counter(values_array_size+1)=1/648;
    else
        values_counter(b)=(values_counter(b)+1)/648;
    end
end

else
    values(1)=columnB(d);
    values_counter(1)=1/648;
end

end


   values
   values_counter
```

Comment: The sum of the probabilities should not more than 1.

Comment: @mbm I think the denominator in all the probabilities in that example is just supposed to be `6`

Comment: Actually in total my dataset has 648 values. I was just giving that as an example if I have 6 values...

Comment: @Zara exactly, your example is wrong which might confuse people. Also exactly why I used numel() as the denominator in my solution so that it works on any size sample.

Comment: You can also try with `format rat` when looking at the output of Dan's method

Comment: Why are people downvoting this!? It's a valid problem, the OP has shown his/her best attempt at solving the problem, comes back to answer comments, ...This question does not deserve to be downvoted!

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis +1. seems like some people here enjoy it, for incomprehensible reason

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thank you for your support. I myself cannot understand why people are voting down without giving any reason in comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid your code is just too convoluted. You're basically trying to find a histogram, so while I'm not telling what's wrong with your code, here is the correct way to do it in Matlab:

```
x = [1;2;3;3;4;1]
egdes = unique(x)
histc(x, edges)/numel(x)
```

I'm not sure where you get your probabilities in your question though...

```
ans =

    0.3333
    0.1667
    0.3333
    0.1667
```

Comment: I have taken the values from an excel file which are 648 in total using this function columnB = xlsread(filename,'B:B');  I just pass columnB in histc (as in your case x is there)?

Comment: @Zara give it a try and see what happens. But yes, just use `columnB` instead of `x`

Comment: I am writing this code egdes = unique(columnB);
histc(columnB, edges)/numel(columnB) and it says ??? Undefined function or variable 'edges'

Comment: If you want to see the histogram use `hist`

Comment: ... or `bar`. There's is no need to recompute the number of occurrences.